# How to share vcpkg library list on github, i tried exporting nuget but it had huge file size

Tags: git, github, nuget, vcpkg

I'm managing thirdparty libraries of my project with vcpkg.
And My project is on github.
I wanna my third party list on github And let people install thirdparty libraries through vcpkg easily like me.
i tried exporting nuget and tried share it. but nuget file was really huge. i couldn't share it.
How can i share my third party library list in vcpkg to github???

Answer (score 0):

Define a vcpkg.json according to:
https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/master/docs/maintainers/manifest-files.md